# tweepy/ twitter api error type

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am using tweepy to make a twitter application. 
When users tweet/update profile, etc, they will get some errors. I want to classify error and give user more information.

```
try:
    tweet/update profile/ follow....

except tweepy.TweepError, e:

    if tweepy.TweepError is "Account update failed: Description is too long (maximum is 160 characters)"
        Do something
    if tweepy.TweepError is "Failed to send request: Invalid request URL: http://api.twitter.com/1/account/update_profile.json?location=%E5%85%B5%E5%BA%A"
        Do something
    if tweepy.TweepError is "[{u'message': u'Over capacity', u'code': 130}]" 
        Do something
```

Is the only way to classify error is to compare `e` with string, for example, `Account update failed: Description is too long (maximum is 160 characters)`?

Answer (score 1):

Right, it is the only way now. There is only one [TweepError](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/error.py) exception defined. It's raised throughout the app with different text.

Here's the relevant open [issue](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/209) on github. So there is a chance that it'll be improved in the future.