# Gracefully handle errors and exceptions for user_timeline method in Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm collecting tweets for a big number of users, so the script will run for days/weeks unsupervised.
I have a list of user_ids in `big_list`.
I think some of the tweets are private and my script stops so I'd like a way for the script to continue on to the next user_id (and maybe print a warning message).

I'd also like suggestions on how to make it robust to other errors or exceptions (for example, for the script to sleep on error or timeout)

This is a summary of what I have:

```
import tweepy
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
my_api = tweepy.API(auth)

for id_str in big_list:
    all_tweets = get_all_tweets(id_str=id_str, api=my_api)
    #Here: insert some tweets into my database
```

The `get_all_tweets` function throws the errors and it basically repeatedly calls:

```
my_api.user_timeline(user_id = id_str, count=200)
```

Just in case, the traceback it gives is the following:

```
/home/username/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tweepy/binder.pyc in execute(self)
    201                 except Exception:
    202                     error_msg = "Twitter error response: status code = %s" % resp.status
--> 203                 raise TweepError(error_msg, resp)
    204 
    205             # Parse the response payload

TweepError: Not authorized.
```

Let me know if you need more details. Thanks!

----------- EDIT --------

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15895515/tweepy-twitter-api-error-type) has some info.

I guess I can try to do a `try/except` block for different type of errors? I don't know of all the relevant, so best practices of someone with field experience would be appreciated!

---------- EDIT 2 -------

I'm getting some `Rate limit exceeded errors` so I'm making the loop sleep like this. The `else` part would handle the "Not authorized" error and some other (unknown?) errors. This still makes me loose an element in the `big_list` though.

```
for id_str in big_list:
    try:
        all_tweets = get_all_tweets(id_str=id_str, api=my_api)
        # HERE: save tweets
    except tweepy.TweepError, e:
        if e == "[{u'message': u'Rate limit exceeded', u'code': 88}]":
            time.sleep(60*5) #Sleep for 5 minutes
        else:
            print e
```

Answer (score 5):

You may just do a "pass" :

```
import tweepy
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
my_api = tweepy.API(auth)

for id_str in big_list:
    try:
        all_tweets = get_all_tweets(id_str=id_str, api=my_api)
    except Exception, e:
         pass
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Your solution works, but I was also looking for a way to handle other relevant exceptions. I edited my question to add one of them (the rate limit exceeded). For the "Not authorized" I can just continue the loop, but for the rate limit exceeded I need to `time.sleep()` on it, otherwise I'll keep getting rejected.

Comment: This should do for different types of exceptions

http://stackoverflow.com/a/17168626/2838313

You may sleep for the required period when you get the rate exception ! (save current state of the loop, meanwhile)

Answer (score 5):

I am really late on this but I faced the same problem during these days. For the need of a time.sleep() I solved the problem thanks to [alecxe reply to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431807/get-all-follower-ids-in-twitter-by-tweepy).

I am diving in the past but I hope this will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use "wait_on_ratelimit" and "wait_on_rate_limit_notify" of Tweepy when you create the API object and add a general tweepy error handling, then, with the specific erros shown, you may try to personalize the code handling each error. It should be something like this:

```
import tweepy 
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret) 
my_api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit = True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify = True)

for id_str in big_list: 
    try: 
        all_tweets = get_all_tweets(id_str=id_str, api=my_api) 
    except tweepy.TweepError as e: 
        print("Tweepy Error: {}".format(e))
```